# Browser Compatablitiy, Support, Modern Browsers and older Versions

Tags: cross-browser, compatibility

This is a question to all web-developers working in the industry more than a few years.

Today the server guy at my work told me that his browser didn't render a Google font I used on a site properly, so I checked his browser - it was Firefox 3.5. (Google font Raleway).. This made me think.. I know for some of our sites its a requirement to support IE6 (larger corporate sites) but for the rest (personal sites) should I be looking at developing for all increments of Firefox, Chrome, IE and Safari?

Does your company still support IE6?

Does your company support previous versions of modern browsers or just the latest ones?

---

And finally, has anyone else had this problem with FF 3.5 and Google Hosted font Raleway..(the font displays extra extra thing so the font is almost unreadable)
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100&v1' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

If anyone's interested I found a working solution to my font problem here:
http://www.jshsolutions.net/google-webfonts-cross-browser-fix-howto/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users of FF/Chrome/Safari usually keep their browsers up to date. Keeping antiques around like IE6 is a corporate thing. Some users keep IE7 and IE8 around due to their unnecessary fear of things breaking. We promise to support the current version of browsers plus one version backwards. If someone wants anything further back than that, there's an extra charge.

Comment: I believe that's right. Any person who is proactive enough to download and use a "good" browser, will keep it updated. Also, "good" browsers, have their updates separate from OS updates and have them applied as soon as they are released - automatically!

Answer (score 1):

Yes I am suffering from the same. We support IE 6,7,8,9 ,FF 3.6,4 and Safari. It seems to be the worst thing to write one code for all this browsers. I never understand why client use IE6. Check this http://ie6countdown.com/ will give you idea about how many are using IE6.

Comment: I understand the plight of developers to have to write code for an increasing number of browsers, but it's our job, isn't it? Many users use IE6 because it is their corporation's standard.

Comment: yeah, Im not so worried about supporting IE6.. I understand that, its more about supporting an ever increasing amount of versions.. example : FF3.5, 3.6, 4, 5..

Comment: @Digbyswift: Yes, Its our job do any anything they want. When it comes to IE6 , I spend one day to write code and 4-5 days to make it work on IE6. If we drop IE6 then its going to make our life much easier.

Comment: Hmm.. While it is our _job_, we still have to consider if it is worth it - monetary as well as technical.

Further, it may be useful and appreciated if you actually educate your clients of using "modern" browsers.

More websites compatible with IE6, the longer it lingers on the web!

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on the user base and also the size of the user base. For example , the user base for governrment sites will be substantially different to personal sites.

A site with 10,000,000 visitors per year with 1% IE6 usage should ideally cater for thoses users. But a site that gets 10,000 visitors a year with 1% IE6 usage could probably afford to ignore IE6.

Answer (score 1):

You should always support the current and prior major release of Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, Safari and Opera. If the client needs an older browser to be supported he should pay extra.

Comment: This just isn't practical. Chrome has reached version 11 since it was released, that's around 2 versions a year. Are you going to penalise the client because your dev team aren't learning the techniques for building backwards compatible css?

Comment: True. This way, you'll lose the client right after the next Chrome release.

Comment: Wait wait, the code for the previous Chrome releases is still there, it doesn't get deleted. For example: the current Chrome version is 11, so version 11 and 10 are supported now, after 5 years, the code for these two releases is still there for backward compatibility, so they are still supported.

Comment: I meant it generally rcode. Not to be specific to chrome. :-)

Comment: @Sterex I know, it was just an example, any other browser can be in it's place, what I tried to say is that you don't have to remove the code for the previous versions when a new release rolls out.

Answer (score 1):

My company supports IE6 for our intranet website - but somewhat reluctantly. However, last quarter, they rolled out mandatory updates for XP systems (IE7 and SP3).

IMO, it is unnecessary to break your head over tweaking CSS for every version of the browser. I'd suggest creating CSS for major versions like IE7, FF3 and webkit-based browsers and have a disclaimer stating the minimum requirements for the website.

Alternatively, you can load content based on the user's browser. Nevertheless, it would be more tedious.

Importantly, check the current browser shares (http://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?spider=1&qprid=0) and decide which browsers you want to support.

Comment: Another way to go about is to have a warning on the page saying that the person is using a deprecated (a bit harsh, I know) browser and they should upgrade/move to a better version to utilize all the features of the website.

Comment: I have done this for my freelance work, a redirect to a static html page with an explanation and links to firefox chrom and IE9.